# Can a son own a gift his father give him

Tags: halacha

If the son Is supported by the father.
can the son aquire a gift from him?

I heard 2 opinions

1 is that no because he can not acquire a Eruv hatzerot for others ([related](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Choshen_Mishpat.270.2?lang=bi) )

2 is that yes since the son aquiers a esrog on sukos

Sources please

Comment: The Etrog case seems pretty conclusive. What sense of ownership are you looking for that isn't covered by Etrog?

Comment: @DoubleAA Is there a source that he is kone the esrog?

Comment: @DoubleAA http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/emunat/31/03104.htm

Comment: @DoubleAA בהקנאה קודם החג יש להחמיר כר"ת וסיעתו ולהקנות אף לגדולים (הסמוכים לשולחן אביהם). ע"י אחר https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/חבל_נחלתו_א_מ

Comment: @DoubleAA footnote 17 here  http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&pgnum=147

Comment: @hazoriz Doesn’t he have to own the esrog, or else it doesn’t count for the mitzvah? ולקחתם **לכם**. Also, if one gives something to a katan with intent that it should belong to the katan, it doesn’t go to his father - certainly if you give it to a gadol.

Comment: @DonielF what is for first point (I agree but do not understand the point of you saying it). yes, but maybe the father can't give him since he is one with him,

Comment: @hazoriz You asked if he is koneh the esrog. The answer is that he has to.

Comment: @DonielF I know he has to, to do the mitzvah. but is he in this case

Comment: @DonielF What hazoriz is saying I think is maybe if the father gives his son a lulav it doesn't work and the son doesn't fulfill the mitzva.

Comment: @DoubleAA And I’m saying that it’s an explicit Halacha that he is koneh it (can’t locate it at the moment, but I could look for it).

Comment: @DonielF if you do that would be  awesome

Answer (score 1):

*I will outline my answer without sources and add them later B"H.*

1. A man's underage daughters are his "property" as he can sell them to slavery or to marriage. (*As he owns their Daas*)
2. A man's sons enjoy financial freedom d'Oraysah, basically, from birth. The only financial relation between a father and a son is two-way inheritance. A father, that by most opinions is obligated to minimally sustain his kids d'Oraysah till they are 6yo, can not sell his sons to a master or force them to work.
3. The sages ruled, that in order to keep Shalom Bays, man's son's earnings and findings will belong to him, but this does not subordinate them financially, and they certainly enjoy their private property.
4. Gifts are of two kinds - personal and not personal. When a gift is "tailored" to the kid, we say it is personal, meaning it can not be transferred to his father (על מנת שאין לאב רשות). E.g. a watch, a phone etc. When a gift is not personal (e.g. money) it falls into the "earnings" category and the father is the rightful owner.
5. When I realized that with my own kids I became very definitive with my kids when buying them numerous gifts, stating explicitly if the gift is all theirs or it stays mine but they can use it with no limitation. Because if it is theirs, they have the right to sell it or to damage it or else, and I didn't mean it.

There's was a story with my eldest son some 15 years ago when I bought him Teffilin for his Bar-Mitzvah. Some 7 years later he asked to buy a new set and I agreed. When I presented him the second set I rightfully took the first, but he objected, stating that this was all his property.

I learned I should be more clear about my intentions.

Comment: +1 Does not על מנת שאין לאב רשות mean that it needs to be said? If said does it not work for money? If not said it should not work even if not money?

Comment: In many situations we follow the "common logic" policy (either "אנן סהדי" or "אזלינן בתר רובא" or "חזקה" or else) to prove the giver's intention. Even if said there should be witnesses etc, depending on who's "המוציא מחבירו" in this situation, as you can't bring witnesses we choose this strategy.

Comment: "(As he owns their Daas)" what does that even mean? "but this does not subordinate them financially" what does that mean?

Comment: Ignore the first, second: sons have no financial responsibilities/obligations towrd their father. Or, they are financially independent. (to my knowledge)